# Is there a missing JavaDoc warning in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I am taking AP Computer Science and my teacher requires JavaDocs. I was wondering if there is a way to make sure that none are missing. I am using Netbeans for the class but I'm sure that others would like to know if it exists for other IDEs too. Also, is there a way to automatically add empty JavaDocs? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate them automatically in Eclipse using a plugin called JAutoDoc. Netbeans 4.0 and up has a feature called Auto Comment which formats your comments to be Javadoc-compliant and also flags up any that are missing, so this appears to be what you're after.

Check out https://netbeans.org/competition/win-with-netbeans/auto-comment.html for details, but the gist is that you select "Auto Comment" from the tools menu.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very strait forward solution. All you have to do is, while you have a file opened, go to the "Tools" menu, and select "Analyze Javadoc." This opens up an other window that lets you select which methods you would like to generate JavaDoc forms for. Once you select the ones you want to add, click "Fix Selected".

Comment: I did wonder if I was 100% accurate on what the option was called, but glad you've figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [checkstyle](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3413/checkstyle-beans) plugin that will show you warning in situation when there is no javadoc for method.

Comment: That plugin seemed to work but was very hard to figure out (but that was my first time installing one) and once I got it it didn't seem very helpful. It just gave out warnings. Most warnings, like the one warning that a comment was over 80 lines, were not useful to me.

Comment: @Nick Huh... perhaps there is a reason why the comment should not be more than 80 lines...!

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans, select your project in the Projects window, then select the "Analyze Javadoc" item from the "Tools" menu. This will produce a report detailing missing or faulty (e.g. missing parameters) Javadoc within the project. I've tested this feature personally in Netbeans 10.0, but I believe it's been there since at least version 8.1.

As an alternative to selecting your entire project in the Projects window, you can also select subgroups of packages or classes to check. This is particularly useful if you're not interested in adding Javadoc to your unit tests: you can just select "Source Packages" and run "Analyze Javadoc" on them without producing warnings about classes in the "Test Packages" group.